# filling in blank parameters for api list from JSON when using rbind.pages?

Tags: json, r, api, foursquare, jsonlite

Working off the foursquare API on the "search" section to pull data on certain places given a longitude and latitude point. During the pull there is one section with  "categories' that is giving me trouble. I've been using a suggestion from a previous question I asked:
[unest list with nested data frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296117/unest-list-with-nested-data-frames-in-r/)

However, that was using the "explore" API from FS where it worked perfectly. Now I am using "search" API and some of the lat long points are pulling in nested data frames where there is no category:

```
                        id               name          pluralName
1 4bf58dd8d48988d1c1941735 Mexican Restaurant Mexican Restaurants
  shortName                                          icon.prefix
1   Mexican https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/mexican_
  icon.suffix primary
1        .png    TRUE

[[14]]
**data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows**

[[15]]
                        id        name   pluralName   shortName
1 4bf58dd8d48988d11b951735 Flower Shop Flower Shops Flower Shop
                                               icon.prefix icon.suffix
1 https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/flowershop_        .png
  primary
1    TRUE
```

**I've relied on cbind since the id is not compatible to merging so. How can I account for these zero's and have the category built out as an 'NA' so that when I bind I don't get the following error? Essentially the unlisting function is killing the zero dataframe, shortening my list to bind**

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 30, 29
```

For reference below is my code:

```
foursquare<-function(x,y,z,r){
    w<-paste("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=",x,
             "&radius=",r,"&oauth_token=",y,"&v=",z,sep="")
    u<-getURL(w)
    test<-fromJSON(u)
    {locationid =""
      locationname=""
      location =""
      lat=""
      long=""
      categories = ""
      checkinscount = ""
      userscount = ""
      beenhere=""
      herenow=""}
    for(n in 1:length(test$response$venues)) {
      #extract
      locationid = test$response$venues$id
      locationname = test$response$venues$name
      location= test$response$venues$location$address
      lat = test$response$venues$location$lat
      long = test$response$venues$location$lng
      categories= test$response$venues$categories
      checkinscount = test$response$venues$stats$checkinsCount
      userscount = test$response$venues$stats$usersCount
      beenhere = test$response$venues$beenHere$unconfirmedCount
      herenow = test$response$venues$hereNow$count


      search_api = as.data.frame(cbind(locationid, locationname, location, lat, long,
                                       checkinscount,userscount, beenhere, herenow))
      print(categories)
      categories = jsonlite::rbind.pages(categories)
      categories = categories[, c("name")]
      print(categories)
      search_api = as.data.frame(cbind(search_api, categories))
    }

    #add columns
    search_api$pulled_date = Sys.time()
    search_api$x_query = paste(x)
    search_api$y_query = y
    search_api$type_api = 'search'
    search_api$radius = paste(r)

    #prep for writeout
    time = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", Sys.time())
    filename <- paste(time,"search_api",".csv", sep="") 
    print(filename)
    write.csv(search_api, file = filename)
  }

  foursquare("40.7575425406984,-73.9295267264121","auth_tok","20161027", 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is categories a vector? Could you fill it with NA?

```
if (length(categories) < 30) {categories <- c(categories, rep(NA, 30 - length(categories)))}
```

Comment: So the issue with this way of running the program is that im sending in various lats and long and the categories vector they return are variable in size, so wouldn't i need something other then "30"?